# Same FLOPs different runtime. Explanation?

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, time-complexity, matrix-multiplication

For an m-by-n matrix, A, where m is much greater than n, the FLOPs to do [QR factorization](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/133A/lectures/qr.pdf) on A is 2mn^2. With another n-by-m matrix, B, the FLOPs to do B*A (matrix multiplication) is also 2mn^2. However, both MATLAB and Python show that matrix multiplication is faster than QR factorization, on my computer by a factor of about 6. I wonder how do we interpret this phenomenon correctly?

Below are my Python codes

```
import numpy as np
import time
t1 = t2 = 0
m = 5000
n = 100
for k in range(100):
    A = np.random.rand(m,n)-0.5
    B = np.random.rand(m,n)-0.5

    tic = time.time()
    Q,R = np.linalg.qr(A)
    t1 += time.time()-tic

    tic = time.time()
    C = B.T @ A
    t2 += time.time()-tic

print('t1=%.3f, t2=%.3f'%(t1,t2))
```

Example outcome:

```
t1=2.246, t2=0.353
```

Comment: An out of cache memory access can cost more than a multiplication. Does the relative cost change with the size of the matrix? If you are seeing a difference in memory access patterns, this should be less important for small N, where most accesses are in cache.

Comment: @mcdowella So can we say the matrix-multiplication is faster because it is more cache-efficient than QR decomposition? (Or, it is implemented in a more cache-efficient way)

Comment: I am not familiar with these libraries so for all I know one is running slower than the other because somebody left debug print statements in :-) But if you find that the difference between the two varies with size of matrix and goes away for small matrices this fits with memory latency and caching. There are a number of different ways both matrix multiplication and QR factorization could be implemented, with different strengths and weaknesses.